# What is a formal word for "good looks"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> It's probably not the best of ideas that a woman marries a younger man. And that is for two reasons; firstly, women reach intellectual maturity much faster than men. Secondly, they lose their **good looks** sooner as well.

What is a formal way of saying "good looks" in the above passage?

Comment: You might find alternatives by looking up "beauty" in a [thesaurus](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2577). Please do have a look at the [tag checklist](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and see what detail can be added to your question. (We don't do proof-reading, so I've removed that request.)

Comment: Isn't it *sexist* to suggest that old women are less attractive / more *unattractive* than old men, in this day and age?

Comment: *Good looks* may well be formal enough for the context, which appears to be relatively informal to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Physical attractiveness

> Physical attractiveness is the degree to which a person's physical features are considered aesthetically pleasing or beautiful. The term often implies sexual attractiveness or desirability, but can also be distinct from either. There are many factors which influence one person's attraction to another, with physical aspects being one of them. Physical attraction itself includes universal perceptions common to all human cultures such as facial symmetry, sociocultural dependent attributes and personal preferences unique to a particular individual.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_attractiveness

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was wondering if there was a more formal word specific to "facial" beauty. Because "beauty" has a much broader meaning and can be used to describe almost all kinds of pleasant qualities. And well, "physical" attractiveness is self explanatory. It includes bodily attractiveness as well.

Comment: @Levi your question is about "good looks", generally. You might want to clarify what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

The simple word “beauty” would work here, as would “attractiveness”. More dated words that might fit include “loveliness”, “beauteousness”, and the truly dated “pulchritude”.

Answer (score -1):

Handsome.  A respectable description, has history of use for women as well as men.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This answer would be much improved with a cited definition and examples.

Comment: *Women lose their **handsome** as they get older?*

Comment: funny, but not to any point